# Change divs twice on different form submissions

Tags: javascript, php, forms, captcha

I have a form with radio buttons in `div1` and a captcha code to be solved in `div2` and another content `div3` Once the person checks a radio button in div1 and clicks submit, div1 is replaced by div2 and when a person completes the captcha in div2, I want div2 to be replaced by div3. But, once I am on div2 and complete the captcha, on submit, div1 is shown again with no signs of div3. Any way to achieve that?

```
<?php
require_once("solvemedialib.php");
$privkey="My_Private_key";
$hashkey="My_Hash_key";
$solvemedia_response = solvemedia_check_answer($privkey,
                $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                $_POST["adcopy_challenge"],
                $_POST["adcopy_response"],
                $hashkey);
if (!$solvemedia_response->is_valid) {
$errCaptcha = '<div class="alert">Please enter the Captcha!</div><br />';
} else {
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#3").css('display', 'block');
$("div#2").replaceWith( $( "#3" ) );
});
</script>
<?php   
}
$genderErr = $gender = "";
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
if (empty($_POST["gender"])) {
$genderErr = "<div class='alert'>Please select a gender.</div>";
} else {
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#2").css('display', 'block');
  $("div#1").replaceWith( $( "#2" ) );
  });
</script>
<?php }}
?>
<div id="1">
<h1>Step 1: Choose your gender</h1>
  <div>
    <form id="genderform" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>" method="post">
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" <?php if (isset($gender) && $gender=="male");?>>Male<br />
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" <?php if (isset($gender) && $gender=="female");?>>Female<br />
    <input form="genderform" id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
    <?php echo $genderErr;?>
    </form> 
  </div>
</div>

<div id="2" style="display:none">
<h1>Step 2: Enter captcha to verify you are not a bot!</h1>
<div align="center">
    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>" method="post">
    <?php echo solvemedia_get_html("My-C-Key"); //outputs the widget ?><br />
    <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
    <?php echo $errCaptcha;?>
</div>
</div>

<div id="3" style="display:none;"><h1>Step3</h1></div>
```

I am sorry if I am doing a silly mistake here. I am new to coding. Please help me out.

Comment: Anyone can help me?

Comment: I believe the page is just being reloaded when you submit the Captcha, and thus div1 is shown again. If you want to give the input a custom submit handler, you can do that with e.g. jQuery https://api.jquery.com/submit/. And to stop the page from being reloaded, remember to put e.preventDefault() in your submit handler as they have in the docs.

Comment: @JuusoLappalainen Thanks a lot. But, I am new to this, if it's not too much to ask, can you tell me how to edit it in a bit more detail. That'd be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

try this .....

```
<?php
  require_once("solvemedialib.php");
  $privkey="My_Private_key";
  $hashkey="My_Hash_key";
  $solvemedia_response = solvemedia_check_answer($privkey,
                                                  $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                                                  $_POST["adcopy_challenge"],
                                                  $_POST["adcopy_response"],
                                                  $hashkey);
  if (!$solvemedia_response->is_valid) {
    $errCaptcha = '<div class="alert">Please enter the Captcha!</div><br />';
  } else {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#3").css('display', 'block');
        $("#1").css('display', 'none');
        $("div#2").css('display', 'none');
      });
    </script>
    <?php
  }

  $genderErr = $gender = "";
  if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    if (empty($_POST["gender"])) {
      $genderErr = "<div class='alert'>Please select a gender.</div>";
    } else {
      ?>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
          $("#2").css('display', 'block');
          $("#3").css('display', 'none');
          $("div#1").css('display', 'none');
        });
      </script>
      <?php 
    }
  }
?>

<div id="1">
  <h1>Step 1: Choose your gender</h1>
    <div>
      <form id="genderform" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>" method="post">
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" <?php if (isset($gender) && $gender=="male");?>>Male<br />
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" <?php if (isset($gender) && $gender=="female");?>>Female<br />
        <input form="genderform" id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
        <?php echo $genderErr;?>
      </form> 
    </div>
</div>

<div id="2" style="display:none">
  <h1>Step 2: Enter captcha to verify you are not a bot!</h1>
  <div align="center">
    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>" method="post">
      <?php echo solvemedia_get_html("My-C-Key"); //outputs the widget ?><br />
      <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
    <?php echo $errCaptcha;?>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="3" style="display:none;"><h1>Step3</h1></div>
```

EDIT
Try this

```
<?php
  require_once("solvemedialib.php");
  $privkey="My_Private_key";
  $hashkey="My_Hash_key";
  $solvemedia_response = solvemedia_check_answer($privkey,
                                                  $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                                                  $_POST["adcopy_challenge"],
                                                  $_POST["adcopy_response"],
                                                  $hashkey);
  if (!$solvemedia_response->is_valid) {
    $errCaptcha = '<div class="alert">Please enter the Captcha!</div><br />';
  } else {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#3").css('display', 'block');
        $("div#2").replaceWith( $( "#3" ) );
      });
    </script>
    <?php
  }

  $genderErr = $gender = "";
  if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    if (empty($_POST["gender"])) {
      $genderErr = "<div class='alert'>Please select a gender.</div>";
    } else {
      ?>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
          $("#2").css('display', 'block');
          $("div#1").replaceWith( $( "#2" ) );
        });
      </script>
      <?php 
    }
  }
?>
<?php  if (!$solvemedia_response->is_valid && !isset($_POST["gender"])) { ?>
<div id="1">
  <h1>Step 1: Choose your gender</h1>
    <div>
      <form id="genderform" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>" method="post">
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" <?php if (isset($gender) && $gender=="male");?>>Male<br />
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" <?php if (isset($gender) && $gender=="female");?>>Female<br />
        <input form="genderform" id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
        <?php echo $genderErr;?>
      </form> 
    </div>
</div>
<?php } ?>

<?php  if (!$solvemedia_response->is_valid  && isset($_POST["gender"])) { ?>
<div id="2" style="display:none">
  <h1>Step 2: Enter captcha to verify you are not a bot!</h1>
  <div align="center">
    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>" method="post">
      <?php echo solvemedia_get_html("My-C-Key"); //outputs the widget ?><br />
      <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
    <?php echo $errCaptcha;?>
  </div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
<?php  if ($solvemedia_response->is_valid  && !isset($_POST["gender"])) { ?>
<div id="3" style="display:none;"><h1>Step3</h1></div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your time, but that didn't work too. it still keeps reverting to div1

Comment: Yes. It still keeps showing me div1 after completing the captcha

Answer (score 0):

I don't think cookies or local storage will work.  My approach would be to store the styling information for each user session on the server side db.  Although node.js would jive well wıth the client sıde javascript, my familiarity with [Python Django](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Sessions) suggests the following possible solution.

```
enter code here

{% block body %}
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <div id="container">User: {{ user.get_username }}
        # conditional python code to render the div styles according to 
        # user preferances
        </div>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```