# Persistent change to CSS for a session

Tags: javascript, php, css, session

I have a `div` (1) with `display:block`, another `div` (2) with `display:none` and a third `div` also with `display:none`.

On each click or form submit I want to change the second `div`'s `display` to `block` and the first's to `none`.

Though this can be done with Javascript, I want this change of CSS to stick for the particular session. How can I attain just that?

Comment: @evolutionxbox I have tried to achieve this with jquery alone with `$("#2").css('display', 'block'); $("div#1").replaceWith( $( "#2" ) );` but when I try to click submit on div2 and try to hide div1 and div2 to show div3, then when the submit button reloads the page, it just reverts to div1 since the change to div1 was not persistent.

Answer (score 1):

One (albeit hacky) way to do this using only client side storage is [SessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage). You could store some value in there, and based on that value set the visibility of the div on page load.

```
/* When the user clicks the form */
sessionStorage.setItem("myValue", "showDiv2");

...    

/* When the page is loaded */
if (sessionStorage.getItem("myValue") === "showDiv2") {
    $('#div2').show();
    $('#div1').hide();
} else {
    $('#div1').show();
    $('#div2').hide();
}
```

There is no way to persistently alter the css source, you can only make modifications to it with javascript after the dom has loaded.

Comment: Can I try to make changes with cookies. BTW, if you can please check out the original question here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42391184/change-divs-twice-on-different-form-submissions I'd really appreciate any help.

Comment: sessionStorage is essentially cookies that get cleared when the user session ends. You can also use localStorage, which stays in the user's browser memory until you clear it or they clear their cookies.

Comment: I tried both and it still reverts back to div1 in this case - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42391184/change-divs-twice-on-different-form-submissions

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
$('#formid').submit(function(e){
        $("#2").css('display', 'block');
        $("div#1").css('display', 'none');
    return false;
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mewwt82x/

Comment: I have already tried that, but when switching to the 3rd div, after completing the form on div2, it just reverts to div1 as the change in div1 and div2 aren't persistent. Please check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42391184/change-divs-twice-on-different-form-submissions